# Why same resources of an angular application are requested again and again while navigating in browsers

Tags: angular, single-page-application

I am developing an angular app whose navigation involves both `a href=<path>` and `Router.navigate(<path>)`. These paths are the same paths for both cases and are made available by the `Routes` object `from '@angular/router'`.

When testing the production bundle with lite-server, I observed that navigations by `Router.navigate(<path>)` didn't reload the app from the the server, but by `a href=<path>` reloaded the same resources (html, css, js) again from the server every time a link is requested:

```
23.11.08 07:09:08 304 GET /index.html
23.11.08 07:09:08 304 GET /runtime.a21fa0e74120b058.js
23.11.08 07:09:08 304 GET /styles.1a9c5f20325d5bf3.css
23.11.08 07:09:08 304 GET /polyfills.79549cd2e9d6a624.js
23.11.08 07:09:08 304 GET /scripts.813213362642cfa0.js
23.11.08 07:09:09 304 GET /main.f20979467e129436.js
23.11.08 07:09:09 304 GET /index.html
23.11.08 07:09:09 304 GET /runtime.a21fa0e74120b058.js
23.11.08 07:09:09 304 GET /polyfills.79549cd2e9d6a624.js
23.11.08 07:09:09 304 GET /main.f20979467e129436.js
23.11.08 07:09:09 304 GET /scripts.813213362642cfa0.js
23.11.08 07:09:09 304 GET /styles.1a9c5f20325d5bf3.css
```

Should `a href=<path>` be NOT used or what did I do wrong? I also wonder if the question / answer is relevant not only for angular but also for any single-page application framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As wrote by [Jaykant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9675804/jaykant)

- Navigating via `Router.navigate()` is client-side
- Opening link will cause a server call

  - To avoid that, use `<a routerLink="..."` instead of `<a href="..."`

But, this is not bad with the correct caching-settings.
Per default - **ALL RESSOURCES** (except `index.html`) should be cached forever. The client should not reload them.
This possible because of the hash in the filename (like `runtime.a21fa0e74120b058.js`)

See [Angular Server Configuration Docs](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration)

### Edit

Your issues have nothing to do with the base url.

Comment: Thanks @akop for the anwer and pointed me to the right direction that I should check server cache settings. And it turned out that lite-server set cache-control header to "public,max-age=0" for all html, css, js (seen in Chrome dev tool, not found any mentioning of cache at https://github.com/johnpapa/lite-server#readme).

Comment: @Mako did it solve your problem? How can I help to solve it?

Comment: Yes, your answer helped me to solve the problem. My problem was mainly to just understand the difference between Router.navigate() and <a href="..." and if <a href="..."> should be used at all. Now I see that with proper cache settings and fallback URL in the server <a href="..."> should also work properly without causing redundant requests to server in case the same resources are requested again by clients. But that is for the real deployment and I think it won't be neccessary to change the cache setting of lite-server which is only used in development test.

Comment: If the navigation is inside your application, you should use `<a [routerLink]="'otherpage'">` instead of `<a href="otherpage">`. In a perfect world, you should do both (avoid a-href and good server-side-settings).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, the issue you are experiencing is that when navigating using `Router.navigate(<path>)`, the app is not being reloaded from the server, but when using `a href=<path>`, the app is being reloaded from the server every time a link is requested.

**This behavior is not specific to Angular, but rather a general behavior of single-page application frameworks.**

One solution to this issue is to set the `base-href` and `deploy-url` parameters to `./` with the build command `ng build --prod --base-href ./ --deploy-url ./`

This way, Angular will use a relative path, and the app will always point to the current path at runtime.

The `a href=<path>` approach is not wrong, but it may not be the best approach for single-page applications. The `router.navigate(<path>)` approach is preferred because it allows for faster navigation and better user experience

Comment: in angular@16.2.0, the option --prod no longer exists for "ng build". I guess the existing option "--output-hashing" is part of prod. I didn't specify "--output-hashing" in the test in my original post, which per Angular doc should apply the default "--output-hashing none" but this was not true. My bundled css and js have hashes as if  "--output-hashing all" were used. Am not aware if the legacy --prod did any more than control output hashes? --deployUrl is warned as "deprecated" in the output of "ng build" and "baseHref" and "APP_BASE_HREF" are recommended, which was already used in my app.

Comment: What I have gotten so far is I should have correct cache settings in server as mentioned by @akop in https://stackoverflow.com/a/77443525/3168315

Answer (score -1):

Use it like this:

Template:

```
<a class="link" href="#" (click)="showCreateAccountForm()">Sign up</a>
```

TS:

```
showCreateAccountForm() {
    this.router.navigate(['/auth/signup/basic-data'], {
      skipLocationChange: true,
    });
    return false;
  }
```

With `return false` there won't be a page refresh.

Comment: There is a [builtin-function](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink) by Angular to exactly don't do that.

Comment: I'm aware of that. If you want to do some other logic upon navigation, it's an alternative to prevent reload.

Comment: @derstauner Thanks for the recommendation. I could verify that your code works (client-side routing is used instead of sending requests to server). However, that was not exactly my question. I questioned what could be done so that the very link in <a hrer="link"> behaves like client-side routing. But of course my phrasing could be misleading due to I am not mastered the topic. Now I got that <a hrer="link"> won't behave like client-routing. Only cache settings may prevent redundant requests to servers.